# Why is a controller not printing to console, when everything is most certainly running properly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a main ViewController. I then added an extension (custom keyboard), and made a KeyboardViewController. In the `viewDidLoad()` method, I have tons of functions that are 100% running, and working properly. If I try t print anything to console using `print()` it doesn't work however, and I am stumped as to why it wouldn't.

Assuming it might have something to do with extension?

Comment: Set breakpoint to line first, to check running on this place.

Comment: breakpoint is properly triggered. the code before and after the print statement is running, as it changes the color of a button and its size, which if I comment out no longer changes the color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone runs into this, the problem is that the logging is happening from the main app, one solution is to run the extension, and all the print logs work as expected. Otherwise, you can also change debug settings.

Answer (score 0):

use `(lldb)` and `po` to print or display anything you want to console.

Comment: I mean print() works just fine in the main ViewController, just not in this extension viewController. Could this be because I'm running the main program, which uses the extension, or something?